# Populate DataTable from different sources using nodejs, ejs and axios

Tags: node.js, datatables, axios, ejs

I need to populate a DataTable with data coming from different sources. I am using a simple express server to get data from 2 different apis (with axios and jsonplaceholder). When i get the data in my server, i send it to the frontend and render it in my table. For each table row i want some of its columns filled with data from source1 and the remaining columns with data from source 2. I'm having problems figuring this last step.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
// test route
app.get('/admin', async (req, res) => {
  // get data from jsonplaceholder
  let [usersApi, postsApi] =  await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'),
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10') 
  ]);
   // check if data is fetched
  console.log('post + users', usersApi.data, postsApi.data);
  // send data to view
  res.render('pages/admin', { apiResponse: [usersApi.data, postsApi.data] });
});
```

Now, in view i pass the data and try to render it, like so

```
<tbody>
     <% apiResponse.forEach((data) => { %>
         <% data.forEach((data) => { %>
             <tr>
                 <td><%= data.name %></td>
                 <td><%= data.username %></td>
                 <td><%= data.email %></td>
                 <td><%= data.phone %></td>
                 <td><%= data.website %></td>
                 <td><%= data.title %></td>
                 <td><%= data.body %></td>
                 </tr>
         <% }); %>
     <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

The table is populated but not as intended, which is having each row fully filled

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5kkH.png)

I've tried a few variations but i can't seem to figure it out. Hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to link the users to the posts. You will have to write some logic to achieve this

Once you have retrieved the users and posts. Loop through the posts and then find the user for a post using the find() method.

```
app.get('/admin', async (req, res) => {
  // get data from jsonplaceholder
  let [userData, postData] =  await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'),
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10') 
  ]);

  const users = userData.data;
  const posts = postData.data;

  posts.forEach((post) => {
    post.user = users.find((user) => { return post.userId == user.id })
  })
 
   // check if data is fetched

  console.log('post + users', usersApi.data, postsApi.data);
  // send data to view
  res.render('pages/admin', { apiResponse: posts });
});
```

And the view will change to this to match the new dataset

```
<tbody>
   <% apiResponse.forEach((post) => { %>
      
       <tr>
           <td><%= post.user.name %></td>
           <td><%= post.user.username %></td>
           <td><%= post.user.email %></td>
           <td><%= post.user.phone %></td>
           <td><%= post.user.website %></td>
           <td><%= post.title %></td>
           <td><%= post.body %></td>
        </tr>
      
   <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi@RedJandal, appreciate your help. There was a 'return' missing and i was getting a 'user' 'undefined'. So i added, like so `posts.forEach((post) => {
    post.user = users.find((user) => { return post.userId == user.id })
  } `  but i'll consider it correct, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @pp_alma good spotting. I edited the answer to reflect this.